# How to create equal spaced values in between unequal spaced values in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have an array A (*variable*) of the form:

```
A = [1, 3, 7, 9, 15, 20, 24]
```

Now I want to create 10 (*variable*) equally spaced values in between values of array A so that I get array B of the form:

```
B = [1, 1.2, 1.4, ... 2.8, 3, 3.4, 3.8, ... , 6.6, 7, 7.2, ..., 23.6, 24]
```

In essence B should always have the values of A and equally spaced values in between values of A.

I did solve this by using the code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 3, 7, 9, 15, 20, 24])
B = []
for i in range(len(A) - 1):
    B = np.append(B, np.linspace(A[i], A[i + 1], 11))
print (B)
```

But does NumPy already have any function or are there any other better methods to create such array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternative method using [interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) instead of concatenation:

```
n = 10
x = np.arange(0, n * len(A), n)       # 0, 10, .., 50, 60
xx = np.arange((len(A) - 1) * n + 1)  # 0, 1, .., 59, 60
B = np.interp(xx, x, A)
```

Result:

```
In [31]: B
Out[31]: 
array([  1. ,   1.2,   1.4,   1.6,   1.8,   2. ,   2.2,   2.4,   2.6,
         2.8,   3. ,   3.4,   3.8,   4.2,   4.6,   5. ,   5.4,   5.8,
         6.2,   6.6,   7. ,   7.2,   7.4,   7.6,   7.8,   8. ,   8.2,
         8.4,   8.6,   8.8,   9. ,   9.6,  10.2,  10.8,  11.4,  12. ,
        12.6,  13.2,  13.8,  14.4,  15. ,  15.5,  16. ,  16.5,  17. ,
        17.5,  18. ,  18.5,  19. ,  19.5,  20. ,  20.4,  20.8,  21.2,
        21.6,  22. ,  22.4,  22.8,  23.2,  23.6,  24. ])
```

This should be faster than the other solutions, since it does not use a Python for-loop, and does not do the many calls to `linspace`. Quick timing comparison:

```
In [58]: timeit np.interp(np.arange((len(A) - 1) * 10 + 1), np.arange(0, 10*len(A), 10), A)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop

In [59]: timeit np.append(np.concatenate([np.linspace(i, j, 10, False) for i, j in zip(A, A[1:])]), A[-1])
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.2 µs per loop

In [60]: timeit np.unique(np.hstack(np.linspace(a, b, 10 + 1) for a, b in zip(A[:-1], A[1:])))
10000 loops, best of 3: 140 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use`zip` function within a list comprehension and `np.concatenate` But as you want the last element too you can append it with `np.append`:

```
>>> np.append(np.concatenate([np.linspace(i, j, 10, False) for i,j in zip(A,A[1:])]),A[-1])
array([  1. ,   1.2,   1.4,   1.6,   1.8,   2. ,   2.2,   2.4,   2.6,
         2.8,   3. ,   3.4,   3.8,   4.2,   4.6,   5. ,   5.4,   5.8,
         6.2,   6.6,   7. ,   7.2,   7.4,   7.6,   7.8,   8. ,   8.2,
         8.4,   8.6,   8.8,   9. ,   9.6,  10.2,  10.8,  11.4,  12. ,
        12.6,  13.2,  13.8,  14.4,  15. ,  15.5,  16. ,  16.5,  17. ,
        17.5,  18. ,  18.5,  19. ,  19.5,  20. ,  20.4,  20.8,  21.2,
        21.6,  22. ,  22.4,  22.8,  23.2,  23.6,  24. ])
```

Also you can use `retstep=True` to return (samples, step), where step is the spacing between samples.

```
>>> np.concatenate([np.linspace(i, j, 10, False,retstep=True) for i,j in zip(A,A[1:])])
array([array([ 1. ,  1.2,  1.4,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  2.8]),
       0.2,
       array([ 3. ,  3.4,  3.8,  4.2,  4.6,  5. ,  5.4,  5.8,  6.2,  6.6]),
       0.4,
       array([ 7. ,  7.2,  7.4,  7.6,  7.8,  8. ,  8.2,  8.4,  8.6,  8.8]),
       0.2,
       array([  9. ,   9.6,  10.2,  10.8,  11.4,  12. ,  12.6,  13.2,  13.8,  14.4]),
       0.6,
       array([ 15. ,  15.5,  16. ,  16.5,  17. ,  17.5,  18. ,  18.5,  19. ,  19.5]),
       0.5,
       array([ 20. ,  20.4,  20.8,  21.2,  21.6,  22. ,  22.4,  22.8,  23.2,  23.6]),
       0.4], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I think OP wants 10 equally spaced variables between the two numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Basically a slightly condensed version of your original approach:

```py
print np.hstack(np.linspace(a, b, 10, endpoint=False) for a, b in zip(A[:-1], A[1:]))
```

Output:

```
[  1.    1.2   1.4   1.6   1.8   2.    2.2   2.4   2.6   2.8   3.    3.4
   3.8   4.2   4.6   5.    5.4   5.8   6.2   6.6   7.    7.2   7.4   7.6
   7.8   8.    8.2   8.4   8.6   8.8   9.    9.6  10.2  10.8  11.4  12.
  12.6  13.2  13.8  14.4  15.   15.5  16.   16.5  17.   17.5  18.   18.5
  19.   19.5  20.   20.4  20.8  21.2  21.6  22.   22.4  22.8  23.2  23.6]
```

The `endpoint` parameter controls whether you have 9 or 10 equally spaced values *in between* two original values.

---

**Edit**

Since you want the 24 at the very end, you can either `append` it like Kasra does or -- to bring up some variation ;) -- forget the `endpoint` argument and generate `10 + 1` values from `a` to `b`. This will append the 24 automatically (since `endpoint` is true by default).
(**Update:** As Bas Swinckels indicates, you need to wrap it with `unique` now...)

```py
print np.unique(np.hstack(np.linspace(a, b, 10 + 1) for a, b in zip(A[:-1], A[1:])))

[  1.    1.2   1.4   1.6   1.8   2.    2.2   2.4   2.6   2.8   3.
   3.4   3.8   4.2   4.6   5.    5.4   5.8   6.2   6.6   7.    7.2
   7.4   7.6   7.8   8.    8.2   8.4   8.6   8.8   9     9.6  10.2
  10.8  11.4  12.   12.6  13.2  13.8  14.4  15.   15.5  16.   16.5
  17.   17.5  18.   18.5  19.   19.5  20.   20.4  20.8  21.2  21.6
  22.   22.4  22.8  23.2  23.6  24. ]
```

Comment: OP wants  `24` on trailing!

Comment: @Kasra: Thanks for the hint! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This does not work either, you now have the internal points like 3 double!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution Code

This solution suggests a vectorized approach using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and `matrix multiplication`.

The basic steps are:

1. Divide a unit-step interval excluding `1` i.e. `[0,1)` into an array of elements of equal step-size and of length `steps`.
2. Then, multiply each of those step array elements with the differentiation of `A` to get a 2D array of offsetted interpolated elements.
3. Finally, add `A` elements for the actual interpolated values.

Here's the implementation -

```
out2D = (np.diff(A)[:,None]*np.arange(steps)/steps) + A[:-1,None]
out = np.append(out2D,A[-1])
```

---

### Benchmarking

The proposed approach seems to be faster than the actual interpolation based approach as suggested in the [`other solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29444822/3293881) for medium to large sized input arrays, as we are working with a regular pattern to interpolate values. Here' some runtime tests to confirm that -

**Case #1: `A` of length `100` and `steps = 10`**

```
In [42]: A = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,100000,(1,100))).ravel()

In [43]: steps = 10

In [44]: %timeit interp_based(A,steps)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 µs per loop

In [45]: %timeit broadcasting_based(A,steps)
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.7 µs per loop
```

**Case #2: `A` of length `500` and `steps = 10`**

```
In [46]: A = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,100000,(1,500))).ravel()

In [47]: steps = 10

In [48]: %timeit interp_based(A,steps)
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop

In [49]: %timeit broadcasting_based(A,steps)
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.8 µs per loop
```

**Case #3: `A` of length `1000` and `steps = 20`**

```
In [50]: A = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,100000,(1,1000))).ravel()

In [51]: steps = 20

In [52]: %timeit interp_based(A,steps)
1000 loops, best of 3: 345 µs per loop

In [53]: %timeit broadcasting_based(A,steps)
10000 loops, best of 3: 139 µs per loop
```